# Solving for _Z in Maple

Tags: roots, maple

I am trying to solve for a variable, k, in terms of all the other variables. Here is the set up:

```
solve({b*(e-f)*k = a-b(c-d-(e-f)/k-f-e)}, {k})
```

However, the solution is in terms of _Z

${k = RootOf(b*_Z*e-b*_Z*f+b((_Z*c-_Z*d-_Z*e-_Z*f-e+f)/_Z)-a)}$

I undrestand that Maple generates variables, and that RootOf is more or less a placeholder but I am wondering how to get k without Z, or what sort of assumptions I should make to get rid of this problem.

Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

In the input, you have accidentally created the function 'b' instead of multiplying by b.  Do this instead:

```
solve({b*(e-f)*k = a-b*(c-d-(e-f)/k-f-e)}, {k})
```

which should give you the expected explicit output.